# Re-natal´s react-native run-ios always runs on simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, re-natal

After signing up for the [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/account/) and running

```
re-natal use-ios-device real 
re-natal use-figwheel
react-native run-ios
```

the simulator is started up instead of the real device. How do I make re-natal connect to the real device?

I've tried following the [React Native guide on Running on Device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html) but that did not change the behaviour of `react-native run-ios`.

It is possible to specify the device you want react-native to use:

```
react-native run-ios --device "rovanion’s iPad"
```

But the iPad is then unable to connect to Figwheel manifesting in a huge red "Network request failed" on the device.